# Object Data Source function returning only 1 value

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, objectdatasource

I am using ObjectDataSource for my Gridview.
The function I am using to return values is just returning a single value that is the last one from the table.
What changes do I make to return all the values.

```
public class Employees
    {
        public int e_number;
        public string e_name;
        public string e_designation;
        private SqlConnection conn = null;
        private SqlCommand cmd = null;
        private string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


        public Employees()
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
        }
        public int Employee
        {
            get
            {
                return e_number;
            }
            set
            {
                e_number = value;
            }
        }

        public  string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return e_name;
            }
            set
            {
                e_name = value;
            }
        }
        public string Designation
        {
            get
            {
                return e_designation;
            }
            set
            {
                e_designation = value;
            }
        }   


        public Employees GetEmployee()
        {
            string strquery = "select [Number],[Name],[Designation] from [Users]";
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = strquery;
             SqlDataReader objSqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int counter = 0;
           // ArrayList myObj = new ArrayList();
          //  Employees objEmployees = new Employees();
            Employees emp = null;

            //if (objSqlDataReader.Read())
            while(objSqlDataReader.Read())
            {
               emp = new Employees();
               // myObj[counter] = new Employees();
              //  Employees employee = new Employees();
                emp.Employee = (int)objSqlDataReader["Number"];
                emp.Name=(string)objSqlDataReader["Name"];
                emp.Designation = (string)objSqlDataReader["Designation"];



               // objEmployees.e_number = (int)objSqlDataReader["Number"];
               // objEmployees.e_name = (string)objSqlDataReader["Name"];
                //objEmployees.e_designation = (string)objSqlDataReader["Designation"];


            }

            conn.Close();
            return emp; 




            //return objEmployees;



        }
    }
}
```

I have tried all approaches like making array of objects but I am not able to .
Please could you tell me what to add in my code.

Comment: you should have a separate Employee class with the properties only and another class EmployeeDataAccess which does the CRUD operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a list of employees.  You are only returning a single one, the last instance after you exit the loop:

```
public List<Employees> GetEmployees()
{
    ..
    List<Employees> emps = new List<Employees>();
    Employees emp = null;

    while (..)
    {
        emp = new Employees();
        ..
        emps.Add(emp);
    }

    return emps;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this as well.
The code works fine except no data gets bound to my Gridview.
what could be the issue?
Earlier in some part of my code I was using 

List<DataRow> listofbadrows = new List<DataRow>();
 listofbadrows.Add(dr);

GridView2.DataSource = listofbadrows.CopyToDataTable();

How do i replicate this for my object Data source

Comment: What does your databinding code look like, i.e., how is your GridView setup and how is the data populated on the columns?  May help to post that as well as an update to your question

Comment: I am just dropping a ObjectDatasource control my the tool box ,configuring it to select the above method for which I posted the code and using the above ObjectDatasource as datasource for the gridview.
Is there some other approach?
I have absolutely no code in the C# for this gridview.

Comment: Hi it is working suddenly now.
I wonder what was wrong earlier?
Could you suggest some additions in the code for the gridview when we are using ObjectDataSource. Im using it for the first time.